# Data storage parallelization in .NET Core

Tags: multithreading, caching, .net-core, data-storage

I am a little lost in this task. There is a requirement for our caching solution to split a large data dictionary into partitions and perform operations on them  in separate threads.

The scenario is: We have a large pool of data that is to be kept in memory (40m rows), the chosen strategy is first to have a Dictionary with int key. This dictionary contains a subset of 16 dictionaries that are keyed by guid and contain a data class.

The number 16 is calculated on startup and indicates CPU core count * 4.

The data class contains a byte[] which is basically a translated set of properties and their values, int pointer to metadata dictionary and checksum.

Then there is a set of control functions that takes care of locking and assigns/retrieves Guid keyed data based on a division of the first segment of guid (8 hex numbers) by divider. This divider is just FFFFFFFF / 16. This way each key will have a corresponding partition assigned.

Now I need to figure out how to perform operations (key lookup, iterations and writes) on these dictionaries in separate threads in parallel? Will I just wrap these operations using Tasks? Or will it be better to load these behemoth dictionaries into separate threads whole?

I have a rough idea how to implement data collectors, that will be the easy part I guess.

Also, is using Dictionaries a good approach? Their size is limited to 3mil rows per partition and if one is full, the control mechanism tries to insert on another server that is using the exact same mechanism.

Is .NET actually a good language to implement this solution?

Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I implemented ReaderWriterLockSlim and implemented concurrent access through System.Threading.Tasks. I also managed to exclude any dataClass object from the storage, now it is only a dictionary of byte[]s.

It's able to store all 40 million rows taking just under 4GB of RAM and through some careful SIMD optimized manipulations performs EQUALS, <, > and SUM operation iterations in under 20ms, so I guess this issue is solved.

Also the concurrency throughput is quite good.

I just wanted to post this in case anybody faces similar issue in the future.